# Angular2 error on subscribe

Tags: angular

I have declared a person object and defined some arrays in constructor. I am calling a method in init method to get all the races.  But I am getting undefined error message in the line "this.person.races.push($(val).attr("title"));"  even though I have declared it in constructor.

```
export class PersonInvolvedComponent {
    person = {}

    constructor(private _globalService:GlobalService) {
        this.person = {
            races: [],
            gender: [],
            builds: [],
            eyeColors: [],
            hairColors: []
        }
    }

    ngOnInit() { 
        this._globalService.applyLanguage("xml/"+this._globalService.getLanguage()+".xml"); 
        this.appendRace();
        this.appendGender();
        this.appendBuild();
        this.appendEyeColor();
        this.appendHairColor();
    }

    appendRace(){
        var config = this._globalService.loadConfiguration('config/personConfig.xml');
        config.subscribe(
            data => { 
                $(data._body).find("racename").each(function(i,val)
                    {
                        this.person.races.push($(val).attr("title"));
                    }
                )},
            err => console.error(err),
            () => console.log('done')
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your call to .each like this :

```
config.subscribe(
        data => { 
            $(data._body).find("racename").each((i,val) => 
                {
                    this.person.races.push($(val).attr("title"));
                }
            )},
        err => console.error(err),
        () => console.log('done')
    );
```

Calling a anonymous function by using the keyword `function` unscope `this`; using lambda you don't and `this` still represent your class

Comment: If this solvers your problem, can you please accept the answer (white check mark below the up/down-vote buttons) to indicate this question is answered. Thanks.